# unspooling cryptic clues

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "unspooling cryptic clues" as "revealing mysterious information". Am I on the right track?

What adds to the problem of understanding is that I could not recognize whether "unspooling cryptic clues" means to be positive or negative.

> The QAnon conspiracy theory supposes that a high-level government agent with Q-level security clearance has been **unspooling cryptic clues** about secret investigations inside Washington, D.C. Some of those investigations involve politicians running a child sex trafficking ring.

> Source: USAToday   [QAnon supporter from Arizona dressed in fur and horns joins storming of US Capitol](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2021/01/06/arizona-qanon-supporter-jake-angeli-joins-storming-us-capitol/6570514002/)

Comment: That probably depends not on English usage, but your point of view.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. It's neither positive or negative. If you spend time looking at what Q deposits, it's a fair statement to say that the clues are cryptic.